# Why does my function require two return statements for it to be correct?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, return

So my coding exercise has me create a function  `“getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty”` that returns an array containing the elements within the array, located at the given key, that are greater than 10. Playing around with the code I cant figure out why my filter method requires two return statements. Any tips to help me understand would be very appreciated.

```
function getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (!Array.isArray(obj[key]) || obj[key].length < 1 ) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return obj[key].filter(function(item){
      return item > 10;
    });
  }
}
```

Also,

- If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
- If the array contains no elements greater than 10, it should return an empty array.
- If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return an empty array.
- If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array

Comment: it has three ... but one is in the callback to filter

Comment: Returns do not cascade upward through function calls, meaning a return in a function does not cause a return in the outer function

Comment: `If the array is empty, it should return an empty array. ... etc` this will do just that - you can even remove `|| obj[key].length < 1` and it'll still do what you want

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.prototype.filter` function returns a new Array using a filter function.
The callback filter function must **return** a Boolean indicating whether or not an item is kept. So...

```
// the outer `return` returns the resulting Array.
return obj[key].filter(function(item){

  // The inner `return` returns a pass/fail (true/false)
  return item > 10;
});
```